# Size of files in subdirectories

Tags: unix, subdirectory, du

I would like to know if there is an easy way to compute the total size of files in subdirectories in unix? I am interested in all the .js files in a folder with subdirectories and I am trying to use du -ah and grep *.js but does not work. Any help is appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -iname "*.js" -ls | awk '{sum += $7} END {print sum}'
```

I dont think there is a way with du, but you can use awk

Comment: thanks. yes with du I would have to dump to a file or something like that which is more work than I want.

Answer (score 0):

This is for all java files:

```
> find . -name "*.java" | xargs du -a | awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
2774
```

so you can modify this to :

```
find . -name "*.js" | xargs du -a | awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below command..... It will print the total at the end...

```
find . -name '*.js' -exec du {} \; | awk 'sum=sum+$1; END{print sum " total" }'
```

Comment: but could I give 2 patters as arg to -name such as '*.png' OR '*.jpeg' is the same command?

Comment: Yes, you can try giving multiple -name like => find . \\( -name "*.png" -o -name "*.jpeg" -o -name "*.js" \\) -exec du {} \; | awk 'sum=sum+$1; END{print sum " total" }'

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name '*.js' -exec stat -c %s '{}' + | awk '{ sum += $0 } END { print sum }'
```